# How Replica Feedback bias circuit rejects supply noise?

Tags: analog, integrated-circuit, feedback, bias, pll

I attached the circuit diagram along with a short description of its working principle. However, it's not clear how the circuit rejects supply noise. It will be great if someone can brief about what exactly happens when-

1. The supply voltage goes up
2. The supply voltage goes down.

[image: diagram]

Comment: Is this in the context of CMOS?

Comment: The circuit is meaningless without context - there are plenty of designs that avoid power supply interactions and the one above states nothing about performance or how the op-amp power supplies are connected.

Answer (score 1):

This is a current sink/source based on the load resistor and the control voltage. If the load is a 1.00 K ohm resistor and the control voltage is 1.00 volts, the current sourced is 1.00 mA. It is a linear scaled loop, so the limit is the positive voltage rail (usually +15) minus the mosfet drop voltage.

The current is buffered by the mosfets, but you cannot put more than +12 volts into the op-amp so with 1 K that is a 12 mA limit. With a 100 ohm load you multiply that by 10, so 120 mA is the limit. 10 ohms may be your finite limit as it would top out at 1.20 amps. Zero current is possible with this circuit.

If Vcc is raised to the op-amps limits then your control voltage is limited to Vcc - 2 volts, due to the output stage of the op-amp. You may be able to push the cntrl voltage close to Vcc but not likely closer than 1/2 volt.
There are single power supply op-amps like the OP220EZ which will work up to 30 VDC. To prevent ringing when changing loads a 22 ohm resistor at the op-amp output will isolate it from the mosfets high gate capacitance.

Any resistor you put at the op-amp output will slow down the loop correction time. Do not use a resistor over 1K ohm or a major change in load will take many uS to correct.

The circuit is a servo-loop, so does not only it regulate current but small ripples in Vcc are ignored. That is they are cancelled out by the same feedback loop. That is why constant current sources and sinks are used very often. For voltage references, current mirrors, amplifier voltage sources, some battery chargers, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please explain from the perspective I mentioned- How the system cancels supply noise and keeps Vcs constant? For example- what happens if supply voltage goes up.

Comment: I added some more paragraphs to clarify those issues.

Answer (score 0):

If \$V_{CC}\$ changes, then the top NMOS transistor will work like a source-follower, changing \$v_{DS}\$ of the current source NMOS transistor.

1. The supply voltage goes up

This causes \$v_{DS}\$ of the current source NMOS transistor to go up as well (because it acts like a source follower), this increases the current a bit as the NMOS transistor has a finite output impedance (\$r_o\$). This causes the output voltage to go down as more current flows to ground than is supplied via the load. This voltage change is detected by the differential amplifier, causing \$v_{CS}\$ to go down as well, pulling the bias current back down to its original level.

2. The supply voltage goes down

The principle is exactly the same, but in opposite directions. \$v_{DS}\$ will increase because of the source follower. The differential amplifier will increase \$v_{CS}\$ to compensate for the increased output voltage, bringing the current back up to its original level.

The bias current becomes independent on \$V_{CC}\$, but on the current through the load.